# Can't mount encrypted disk from old cryptsetup

Tags: usb-drive, fsck, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I've got a very old USB disk, on which there's a very old encrypted partition.

It mounts as `/dev/sdb1`

On a newish box (with cryptsetup 1.7.3), I can attach to it with:

```
cryptsetup -c aes-plain -s 128 -h sha256 create wdexternal /dev/sdb1
```

But on an older box with (cryptsetup 1.6.1), that results in a /dev/mapper/wdexternal that doesn't look like a filesystem (according to fsck)

I've also tried the old command:

```
cryptsetup open /dev/sdb1 wdexternal
```

which my notes tell me used to work back in the day, but that gives

```
Device /dev/sdb1 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Anyone know what's going on/how to fix it/how to go about understanding the problem?

Answer (score 2):

LUKS is just one of several encryption methods that `cryptsetup` supports.

`cryptsetup create` is for plain, non-LUKS encrypted devices. As such, there is no LUKS header, no metadata, no specification of ciphers, no key derivation / bruteforce protection.

Without a metadata header, `cryptsetup` can't figure out which encryption mode to use. Hence you more or less have to use the full command that specifies all ciphers involved manually. Other commands might have worked in the past (I can't verify right now), but in general with plain mode, if you don't specify *everything* on the command line, you rely on default choices and defaults change over time, so it's not reliable.

The main issue with not using LUKS (with default settings) is that it's easy to pick the wrong cipher. Consider backing up and re-encrypting this data - with LUKS, if you want the simple open command to work.